# How can I get the list of UTF-8 files in a UTF-8 directory using C or C++?

Tags: c++, file, utf-8, directory

I ended up in here

[How can I get the list of files in a directory using C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c)

I am afraid none of the codes support UTF-8. I modified Bad's code a bit to accept the UTF-8 directory.

```
//#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 3
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/detail/utf8_codecvt_facet.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    boost::filesystem::detail::utf8_codecvt_facet utf8;
    boost::filesystem::path p;
    p.assign(u8"C:\\", utf8);

    for (auto i = directory_iterator(p); i != directory_iterator(); i++)
    {
        if (!is_directory(i->path())) //we eliminate directories
        {
            cout << u8"Fil:" + i-> path().filename().string() << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << u8"Dir:" + i-> path().filename().string() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to get the UTF-8 files output.

Comment: Just curious, why UTF8 file paths on MS Windows?

Comment: Because it's the right thing to do. All character data should be UTF-8, all the time.

Comment: Because user do this. Like [http://i39.tinypic.com/zvtw2g.png](http://i39.tinypic.com/zvtw2g.png) from [https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/use-meiryo-ui-instead-of-meiryo-for-japanese-text/5099a159-912f-48f4-b1de-01acf6f7c426](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/use-meiryo-ui-instead-of-meiryo-for-japanese-text/5099a159-912f-48f4-b1de-01acf6f7c426)

Comment: That's not C! Don't spam tags.

Comment: Sorry for spamming the tag. Because I am still a newbie, I don't know how to use the correct tag so I just copied the original post tags, including tag c, plus the utf8. Except that I cannot think of anything.